# zimbra nginx proxy failed to start

Tags: zimbra

I installed Zimbra the problem start when i want to login to Zimbra admin area does not work i restarted it i find that nginx proxy Failed to start

```
Starting nginx...nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:143 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:993 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:110 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:995 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
failed.
```